# How to combine HTML with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html

When I run the HTML page then my PYTHON Program must be called after clicking the button.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
            function clicked()
            {
                // call python program
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick = "clicked()" id="b1">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Python Programs:**

```
print("Hii")
```

Comment: You can use Ajax to do this, send request to a Python backend (use a framwork like Flask for example) where the request is handled.

Comment: Where do you want your Python program to be executed? In the browser or in the server?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to send a request to an endpoint implemented by Python.